# Find path of button in browser for Applescript

Tags: macos, browser, applescript

I'm trying to click on a button in Safari with Applescript.

I know the code must be something like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click button " ENTER " of group 1 of ... of group 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

but I can't find the right series "group of group of".

With UI Inspector, I got this:

[image: http://cl.ly/image/0U0t1V1J1p08]

Any help? What do I need to write and why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        get every button of every group of every UI element of every scroll area of every group of every group of every group of window "CHALCO.net"
    end tell
end tell
```

The location of the button should be in the result.

Comment: "It's a long way to the top" but it works!!
It's difficult in a page with a lot of elements, but I can export the resault and then use a find function :)